# How to get Geography data to GeoJson in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am using PostgreSQL database and there is a field in a table(area) i.e. geog `pulic.geography(Points,4326)`. It contains below type of records

`0101000020E6100000BA83D89942334540780B24287ED051C0`

I am using `ST_AsGeoJson()`, to get the `GeoJson` through above types of records.

My database is connected and I am using a query to fetch result i.e.

`$query="SELECT  ST_AsGeoJSON(geog) FROM area";`

But I am getting below warning and not getting any results

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: function
>   st_asgeojson(public.geography) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT
>   ST_AsGeoJSON(geog) FROM public.area ^ HINT: No function matches the
>   given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type
>   casts. in /home/domain/public_html/sg_database.php on line 20"

Please suggest regarding this..

Thanks

Comment: Please do not [cross post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132573/how-to-get-geography-data-to-geojson-in-postgresql).